# VB LINQ to SQL update

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I am trying to updated a SQL table using `LINQ`. It keeps trying to update the first record in the table. If I select the first record it will successfully update that record but if I try to update any other record it says I am trying to change the CategoryID which is the PK so it will not change it.
 
I have tried several variations of this with no luck.

```
Imports System.Data.Linq
Public Class frmUpdate
Dim db As New DataClasses1DataContext
Dim catnum As Integer
Private Sub frmUpdate_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim query = From aCat In db.Categories
                Select aCat

    CategoryBindingSource.DataSource = query
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Try
        catnum = CInt(CategoryIDComboBox.Text())
        Dim catQuery As Category = (From aCat In db.Categories
                    Where aCat.CategoryID = catnum
                    Select aCat).First()

        catQuery.CategoryID = catnum
        catQuery.CategoryName = CategoryNameTextBox.Text.ToString()
        catQuery.Description = DescriptionTextBox.Text.ToString()

        db.SubmitChanges()
        frmGridView.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It appears that you are setting the categoryId to a combo box. Assuming this is WPF or Winforms, you may be running into databinding issues. Since you are persistning the context, you should be able to just rely on databinding to update your values and then call db.SubmitChanges to apply the changes without manually setting the values in code. It might be helpful to know how the combobox works in relation to your form to give a more informed response.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the line

```
catQuery.CategoryID = catnum
```

The object already has the value because that's how you found it. Apparently, assigning the same value to it is seen as a change.

Comment: I have tried this with and without this line.  Same error message both ways.

Comment: Looks impossible with your code. What's the exact exception? (And inner exception, if any). Have got any added code in `Category` itself?

Comment: Value of member 'CategoryID' of an object of type 'Category' changed/  A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.  Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead.

Comment: i tried doing an inner exception and all i got was a blank popup box

Comment: I think the BindingSource may cause false assignments. Try `Dim query = From aCat In db.Categories.AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: well I just figured it out.  Apparently in my combobox i had the formatting enabled properly set to True, this was causing the category ID to change on the first record to match whatever record was selected.  Thank you for your suggestions.  The effort was greatly appreciated.